# How to let iphone connect json server API for debug?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ip-address, json-server

I have try to use json server to call my API sample.
In simulator, I use this code to call API successfully.

```
//json-server -w db.json

var request = try self.buildRequestNew(requestHeader: requestHeader, from: route)

let testUrl = route.baseURL.appendingPathComponent("\(route.path)")

if testUrl == URL(string: "https://xxxxxxxxxxx.com.tw/xxxxxxx/rest/test1") {
       request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://localhost:3000/test1")!) //my request change this URL.
       request.httpMethod = "GET"
}
```

But when I connect iphone, it's fail.
I need to do what and change what ip address to let my API call successfully.
Thanks

Comment: Is the iPhone connected to the local network where you have hosted this API?

Comment: @Frankenstein I just connect the same wifi, and what should I do or setting what?

Comment: Check if you device is able to access the network. Try it out on safari.

Answer (score 0):

When running in the simulator, `localhost` is the address of your development machine. Running on the phone, `localhost` refers to the phone, so you need to replace that with the hostname or IP address of your Mac. We can't tell you what that is exactly, you'll have to figue that out e.g. from System Preferences > Network.

Comment: I use ios 13.4.1 and I try to add HTTP Proxy Server falied, so I don't know how to connect.